# How was the behavior of Agni before he was cursed by Bhrigu?

Tags: curse, agni

How was the behavior of Agni before he was cursed by Bhrigu to be "Sarva bhakshakha" (consumer of all things)?

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

After the curse of Agni by Bhrigu, Lord Brahma told Agni [this](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01008.htm):

> The flame that is in your viler parts shall alone eat of all things
>   alike. The body of yours which eats flesh (being in the stomach of all
>   carnivorous animals) shall also eat all things promiscuously.

Before the curse, Agni was apparently not in the stomach of animals as the *Vaishvanara Agni*, which causes digestion.

Comment: If Agni was not in the stomach of Animals before the curse then how did the digestion happen

Comment: They were probably turiya, without any function of agni, so they wouldn't have hunger

Comment: @AmruthKumar Good question, I'm not sure, maybe another Devata was responsible for digestion.

Answer (score 1):

There was no mention of Agni getting cursed by Bhrigu in Rig Veda.  Agni used to consume everything even before that.

Rig Veda [I.98.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01098.htm) eulogises Agni as **Vaiśvānara**

> Present in heaven, in earth, all-present Agni,—all plants that grow on
>   ground hath he pervaded. May Agni, may Vaiśvānara with vigour,
>   present, preserve us day and night from foemen.

Agni was eulogised as the God in the very [first hymn of Rig Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01001.htm).

> May Agni, sapient-minded Priest, truthful, most gloriously great, **The
>   God**, come hither with the Gods.

Then how can he be cursed by a sage?

In Puranas, [Bhrigu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhrigu) was stated to be the son-in-law of Daksha.  Even before the incident of Bhrigu cursing Agni, people used to live and die.  And, Agni was the medium for their day-to-day affairs.

This must be an interpolated story.

Comment: Then how can he be cursed by a sage? 


A sage can curse a god. Gandhari cursed Krishna is a best example.

Comment: I'm talking about vedas, where the God was praised as formless.   Puranas contain many such stories of sages cursing the God. @hanugm

Comment: Oh! but do vedas say that god cannot be cursed?

Comment: @hanugm:Can you quote such instances from Vedas, please?

Comment: No. I am asking you that whether any veda say that a god cannot be cursed. If there is such statement, then we can accept that Bhrigu cannot curse Agni.

Comment: @hanugm: As far as I understood, there were no such instances. If someone quote such instances, I will correct myself:-)